# DocumentReference.get(<Field>) Not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am simply trying to find this boolean value, and if it's true, then it would execute a code. Or else, it would execute another code. I cannot seem to read this boolean value in Firebase.

[This is the data I am trying to read.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYfZC.png)

It says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#get) that I can do `.get(fieldPath)` but I might be doing it wrong. Firebase documentation is really bad. haha

```html
checkIfLoggedIn = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('users')
          .doc(uid)
          .get('uid.isStore')
          .then(snapshot => {
            // Trying to find how to do this
            console.log(snapshot);
          });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('mainNav');
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('signup');
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is logic similar to:

```
db.collection('users')
  .doc(uid)
  .get()
  .then(documentSnapshot => {
    let isStore = documentSnapshot.get('isStore');
    // Value of isStore here ... 
  });
```

The chain is:

- `db.collection` -> `CollectionReference`
- `CollectionReference.doc()` -> `DocumentReference`
- `DocumentReference.get()` -> `Promise<DocumentSnapshot>`
- `DocumentSnapshot.get()` -> field value

See also:

- [CollectionReference.doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc)
- [DocumentReference.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get)
- [DocumentSnapshot.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#get)

Comment: How can I get the DocumentSnapshot? Would I have to do `DocumentReference.get().then(DocumentSnapshot => {...})`?

Comment: Apologies ... I neglected to notice that my original text contained angle brackets which were not shown in the response.  The call to DocumentReference.get() returns a JavaScript promise which, when resolved returns a DocumentSnapshot.  So YES you understand correctly ... in your comment above you have it exactly correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been frustrated with this forever.